# Second monitor doesn't wake after kernel update in Fedora Core 20

Tags: linux, fedora, multi-monitor, radeon, displayport

I have an odd problem with my dual monitor setup. The base system is a Dell 6005 desktop with an ATI Radeon card. My primary monitor is an HP 23", while the second monitor is an HP 20". The primary is connected via VGA, while the second is connected via a DisplayPort-to-VGA adaptor.

With kernel 3.14.9-200.fc20.x86_64, everything works fine.

After updating to kernel 3.15.8-200.fc20.x86_64, the second monitor is no longer taken out of standby (sleep) mode.

xrandr reports two monitors and the output is identical for both kernels.

The only difference I see is that I see the following errors in dmesg when running the 3.15 kernel...

```
[    1.914501] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train_cr] *ERROR* clock recovery reached max voltage
[    1.914502] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train_cr] *ERROR* clock recovery failed
```

I found one other post that was similar to this, but there was no solution.

Has anyone else seen and solved this, or can anyone give me a place to look further as far as logs/configs are concerned?